# How to add contact form on facebook personal/people profile page?

Tags: facebook, forms, profile

I found several apps that allows us to add contact forms in a facebook FAN page.

But i couldnt find any that works on personal/people profile pages.

So, is there a way to add a form on my profile pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no API to include data into a user's profile page like this, thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in a personal page!